# Convex set for a set of points in 2d plane

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

There are set of five points $A(0,0) ,B(1,1) ,C(2,0) ,D(2,2).E(0,2) F(1.5,1.5)$

$S=\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$

[image]

Please tell me whether my understanding is correct or not!

1. The points $A,C,D,E$ forms a convex set for $S$.(i.e the convex set of $S$ contains $A,C,D,E$ and not all points of $S$).
2. If asked whether Set $S$ is a convex set or not the answer is no.
3. The convex set of a set $S$ need not contain all the points in $S$.

Comment: I can't see how to interpret the wording in 1. to make it true, or even plausible.  A convex set $X$ must include all points "between" two of its points,  i.e. the line segment connecting any two of the points in $X$.  Given a set $S$ in the plane, there is a smallest set $X$ containing $S$ that is convex.  We say $X$ is the convex closure of $S$ (many would say "convex hull" but this is a pet peeve of mine).

Answer (score 1):

The points $A,C,D,E$ do **not** form a convex set. This in the sense that set $\{A,C,D,E\}$ is not a convex set. You could highly say that the square marked by corners $A,C,D,E$ is convex. This square is the smallest convex set that contains these points. Secondly, it also contains the points $B$ and $F$ so that it also is the smallest convex set that contains set $S$. It is also named the **convex hull** of set $S$. I think that you call it the convex set of set $S$. Set $S$ is not convex. A set is convex iff it coincides with its convex hull.

Comment: so All the set of points enclosed between AC,CD,DE,EA form convex set for set S.
And if i consider all the set of points enlosed by AB,BC,CD,DE,EA DO NOT form a convex set for S.Is this correct?
Am i correct in saying "so and so" points do not / do form a convex set for S?

Comment: the set of points enclosed by AC,CD,DE,EA form indeed a convex set. Secondly every point of $S$ belongs to it. It is the convex hull of $S$. The set of points enclosed by AB,BC,CD,DE,EA do not form a convex set. Point $(1,0)$ lies on AC but does not belong to this set. This shows that the set is not convex. The statement: these points form a convex set for $S$ is peculiar. I would expect something like: the convex hull of these points coincides with the convex hull of $S$. Also note the difference between linesegments (and being enclosed by them) and just points.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the convex set has to be convex, and $\{A,C,D,E\}$ is not, e.g. it does not contain the line from $A$ to $E$.

[The convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) is the whole set, not only its boundary.

$\hspace{70pt}$[image: convex hull example]

Be aware, that algorithms that calculate the convex hull actually only output its boundary. This is because it is impractical to generate an infinite output. Hence, a finite representation is required and the boundary is exactly such a thing (i.e. it is finite if the input set itself was finite).

To conclude, your convex set is the whole rectangle with $A,C,D,E$ as corners.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: so All the set of points enclosed between AC,CD,DE,EA form convex set for set S. And if i consider all the set of points enlosed by AB,BC,CD,DE,EA DO NOT form a convex set for S.Is this correct? Am i correct in saying "so and so" points do not / do form a convex set for S?